# Load external phtml file on product page

Tags: product, phtml, product-page

I want to load a custom .phtml file on product page.
I just did this:

Inside view.phtml I added this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('short_specificaties'); ?>
```

In local.xml I added this line inside `<reference name="product.info">` :

```
<block type="core/template" name="short_specificaties" as="short_specificaties" template="catalog/product/view/shortspecs.phtml"/>
```

And inside the shortspecs.phtml I added this code:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
    $helperSnippets = $this->helper('ultimo/rsnippets');
?>

<?php $yourCatIds = array(235);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_display_diagonal_944_1') . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_processor_family_2196_1') . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_internal_memory_11381_1') . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_total_storage_capac_3318_1') . '</li>';
}
?>
```

But that breaks down the page.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jelle,there issue with block type.As you call  `product view class` functions.So,it block type should be `type="catalog/product_view"`  from `type="core/template"`